# Animation effect not working with IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, intersection-observer

I'm adding some effects to my website. First I added a translate effect and it worked fine. I have an InsersectionObserver that only triggers the effect when the users gets to that section. Then I added a fadein animation that also works but for some reason is triggered when the website loads, and not when I get to that section. That means the effect is "lost", the person won't see it.

```
.vision-box-animation{
  /* Animation Settings */
  transform: translateY(+100px);
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  100% { opacity: 1;}
}

.up{
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform ease 1s;
}

let timer = 0;
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    let intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            setTimeout(function() { entry.target.classList.add('up'); }, timer);
            timer += 50;
            intersectionObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
          }
        });
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.vision-box-animation').forEach(obj => {
      intersectionObserver.observe(obj);
    });
  });
```

What I am doing wrong? I want the fade in effect to also trigger only when the person reaches that section of the website.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a css animation, it will run as soon as:

- the element is in the dom.
- the elements css specifies an animation.

In your case, as soon as the page is loaded.
the divs are in the dom & `.vision-box-animation` has specified an animation. thus it will run immediately.

The `intersectionObserver` is applying a new class. `.up`; you could move your animation to that class.
So the element only specifies an animation once the `.up` class is added

## Example:

```js
let timer = 0;
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // orginal code,
  let intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          entry.target.classList.add('up');
        }, timer);
        timer += 50;
        intersectionObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll('.vision-box-animation').forEach(obj => {
    intersectionObserver.observe(obj);
  });

  // modified code, notice _up-animated_ class that will be applied
  let intersectionObserver2 = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          entry.target.classList.add('up-animated');
        }, timer);
        timer += 50;
        intersectionObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll('.vision-box').forEach(obj => {
    intersectionObserver2.observe(obj);
  });
});
```

```css
.vision-box,
.vision-box-animation {
  /* Animation Settings */
  transform: translateY(+100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.vision-box-animation {
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.up,
.up-animated {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform ease 1s;
}


/* this class has the animation as well as the transition*/
.up-animated {
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: orange;
}

.three {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.four {
  background-color: green;
}

.five {
  background-color: blue;
}

.six {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.seven {
  background-color: violet;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="box">
    with fix:
    <div class="vision-box one">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box two">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box three">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box four">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box five">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box six">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box seven">
      7
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    without fix:
    <div class="vision-box-animation one">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box-animation two">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box-animation three">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box-animation four">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box-animation five">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box-animation six">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="vision-box-animation seven">
      7
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```